# Priority for NO, then Yes, then blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I've been stuck at this for hours.
I'm supposed to Input either a "Yes" or "No" or blank for 12 columns in a single row.
However I need a formula to Prioritize "NO" over the other answers.
But:

1. if there isn't "NO", but there's "YES" and blanks, then the cell should reflect "YES"
2. If there isn't "NO" or "YES", the cell should be blank

I tried Match and CountIF formula but i can't get the result i need.
I also tried this =IF(F7:Q7="NO","NO",IF(F7:Q7="YES","YES",IF(F7:Q7="","",0)))

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into using `And` and `Or` functions along with IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there isn't "NO", but there's "YES" and blanks, then the cell should reflect "YES"
> If there isn't "NO" or "YES", the cell should be blank
> =IF(F7:Q7="NO","NO",IF(F7:Q7="YES","YES",IF(F7:Q7="","",0)))

You mean like this?

`=IF(COUNTIF(F7:Q7,"NO"),"NO",IF(COUNTIF(F7:Q7,"YES"),"YES",IF(COUNTA(F7:Q7)=0,"",0)))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can search your range for values, then use an `IF` statement.

For example:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("No",$C2:$E2,0)),"No",
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Yes",$C2:$E2,0)),"Yes",""))
```

[image]